# Change color of bar in a Pentaho CDE Barchart

Tags: colors, bar-chart, pentaho-cde

as the topic states i am not quite sure how to change the color of the bar that the user in the CDE Dashboards barchart selects.
In the clickaction() method i would like to do something like

```
function f() {
    var mychart = this;
    var bar = mychart.getSelection();
    bar.color('red');
}
```

Can someone help me with this? The main problem is that i am not quite sure where i can find the documentation of all objects and methods that i can use in JS. Like is there a way to get access to a specific object in the Dashboard? Like:

```
var chartXY = Dashboards.getObject('Chart XY');
```

I hope anyone can provide some helpful links or some documentation of all methods that can be used in JS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i managed it by myself and want to share it with you guys.
I did it like this, in the PreExecution i added:

```
function changeBars(){
var cccOptions = this.chartDefinition;

// For changing extension points, a little more work is required:
var eps = Dashboards.propertiesArrayToObject(cccOptions.extensionPoints);

// add extension points:
eps.bar_fillStyle = function getColor(){
    var val = this.scene.vars.value.value;
    var atom = this.scene.atoms;
    var category = atom.category.label;

    if(category == selection_param){
        return "red";
    }else{
        return "blue";
    }
};

// Serialize back eps into cccOptions
cccOptions.extensionPoints = Dashboards.objectToPropertiesArray(eps);
}
```

You need to listen for the selected_param which will be set every time a bar of the particular chart is selected. I hope this is helpful. Also in case there is a more elegant way please let me know.